# Is boost managed_mapped_file using my physical memory?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, boost, mmap

I want to map a file(512M) to shared memory so that every process can access it. And I choose boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file.

I think shared memory should not take `real` memory because it is shared by multiple processes. But when I run my program, it seems that every process has used 512M of memory. And there is not enough memory for 20 processes.

So why is boost::interprocess::managed_mapped_file taking real memory but not virtual memory?

Comment: Just try it. I think your mistaking the virt set with the reserved/committed set.

Comment: Yes it's is using your physical memory, but only as much as available. Otherwise, unlocked pages (which could be all of them) will be swapped out of the physical memory. The pages will be still mapped into you virtual address space of course, until you unmap. Swapping dirty pages out requires a write and swapping pages back in requires a read, so having too few physical pages available to "back" your virtual filemapping could lead to very bad performance.

Answer (score 1):

> I think shared memory should not take real memory

No, you'll need up to 512M of "real" memory (although this might be paged in and out of physical memory on demand). Each process will use that memory.

> it seems that every process has used 512M of memory

Each will have 512M of shared memory mapped into its virtual address space; presumably that's what you're seeing. It will be the same 512M of physical memory behind each mapping.

> And there is not enough memory for 20 processes.

Are you saying you actually run out of physical memory, as if each process allocated 512M of it? If each process is taking physical memory for itself, and not sharing it, then something is going wrong when you create and share the virtual memory. We'd need to see how you're doing that to guess what might be going wrong.

Comment: _No, you'll need 512M of "real" memory_ - that's not accurate. That's only required if you VirtualLock or mlock those in place

Comment: @sehe: Indeed, I was being slightly loose with my language, and hoping the meaning would be clear enough. By "you'll need real memory", I meant "you'll need pages allocated for as much of the  memory as is used, each of which will need physical memory at the time it's accessed."

Comment: Point is, you need only say a couple of pages (let's take 40k) to map a file of 21GiB usefully. (The rest will just be swapped in/out based on LRU barring locking)

Comment: @sehe: OK, we're using the word "real" to mean different things. Hopefully I've clarified the answer enough, without needing too much of a lecture on memory management. Feel free to write your own, if you don't think this has a sufficient level of pedantry.

Comment: @sehe 40k may not be enough to map a file of 21GiB usefully, think of a database shared by 20 processes serving realtime requests - that would be a clear case where trading cheap memory for lower latency is an excellent tradeoff.